# How to measure touch pressure (keystroke) on iOS system keyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, keystroke

Probably there is no way to measure touch pressure using a custom `UIGestureRecognizer`, since we cannot directly access the system keyboard's view [1]. It can be achieved if a custom `inputViewController` is used but it's not an option for me. I want to store key hold time and key press pressure for each key. Do you know a way to do this?

Edit: [1] I said "We cannot directly access the system keyboard's view." but actually we can:
`UIRemoteKeyboardWindow > InputSetContainerView > InputSetHostView`.

I think that an improvement to Nirav Bhatt's answer may solve this issue but it disables the functionality of touches on the keyboard view. When I touch on a key, it outputs force of touch but the corresponding letter isn't typed to text field.

Comment: Can you subclass the system keyboard, override touchesBegan, get the force there and then call `super.touchesBegan(..)`? You‘d somehow get Swift to return the right Keyboard class though. And give the class the right place to deliver the seen force, or maybe to a static function.

Comment: You could also create a Proxy which implements touchesBegan, etc where you put through the calls to UIRemoteKeyboardWindow but the while piping the seen force to the place you want it. And return said Proxy in hitTest instead of the keyboard window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is easier than I think. For iOS 9+ systems, we can follow these steps to access system keyboard and listen keystroke...

At first, create a custom `UIGestureRecognizer` to listen keystroke. The implementation of this step is skipped, since it's trivial (just override `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, `touchesEnded`).

Add `KeyboardManager` to access keyboard view:

```
final class KeyboardManager {

    static let shared = KeyboardManager()

    private init() { }

    /// Returns keyboard view on application window
    ///
    /// - Returns: Keyboard view
    func keyboardView() -> UIView? {
        for window in UIApplication.shared.windows {
            if let keyboardView = keyboardViewFromWindow(window) {
                return keyboardView
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    /// Returns keyboard view from given window
    ///
    /// - Parameter window: Keyboard view container candidate window
    /// - Returns: Keyboard view
    func keyboardViewFromWindow(_ window: UIWindow) -> UIView? {
        if window.hasClassNameSuffix("UIRemoteKeyboardWindow") {
            let inputSetContainerView = window.subview(withSuffix: "InputSetContainerView")
            let inputSetHostView = inputSetContainerView?.subview(withSuffix: "InputSetHostView")
            return inputSetHostView
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

`UIView` extension functions used above:

```
@nonobjc extension UIView {

    /// Returns first found subview with given class name
    ///
    /// - Parameter className: Subview class name
    /// - Returns: First subview with given class name
    func subview(withSuffix className: String) -> UIView? {
        return subviews.first {
            $0.hasClassNameSuffix(className)
        }
    }

    /// Compares suffix of view class name with given name
    ///
    /// - Parameter className: Class name that will be compared
    /// - Returns: Comparison result of view class name and given name
    func hasClassNameSuffix(_ className: String) -> Bool {
        return NSStringFromClass(type(of: self)).hasSuffix(className)
    }
}
```

Then, add your gesture recognizer to keyboard view using below functions:

`KeyboardManager.shared.keyboardView()?.addGestureRecognizer(keyboardGestureRecognizer)`.

*Note: Your gesture recognizer shouldn't extend `UITapGestureRecognizer`. `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` is okay. We cannot add multiple tap gesture recognizers with same type to a view.*

Answer (score 3):

Since iOS 9, as part of 3D touch, [UITouch has got force property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitouch/1618110-force) that gets you exactly the pressure applied during touch event.

You may combine this with your custom view implementation with each alphanumeric characters as UIButtons receiving touch, and passing it along.

**UPDATE:**

After some haggling with `UIWindow`, I was finally able to trap touch events within apple's standard keyboard window.

The trick is to override `hittest` within `UIWindow` extension (could be done on `UIView` level as well, but it would have wider implications because `UIView` is ancestor of `UIWindow`), and return touch handling object whenever you see touches emanating from `UIRemoteKeyboardWindow`.

```
extension UIWindow
{
    override open func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
    {
        print("kb touch")

        for touch in touches
        {
           let pressure = touch.force
           print("pressure is: \(String(describing: pressure))")
        }
    }

    override open func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        print("hittest")

        let view = super.hitTest(point, with: event)

        if (NSStringFromClass(type(of: self)) == "UIRemoteKeyboardWindow")
        {
            //will result in touchesBegan being called
            return self;
        }

        return view
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm familiar with 3D Touch but as I said, using custom keyboard isn't an option for me. I need to find a way to work it with the system keyboard.

Comment: I am wondering what kind of app requirement would demand keystroke pressure to be known, all using Apple inbuilt keyboard. You could probably measure the time between two successive keystrokes in textField beginediting callback, if that serves in lieu of measuring pressure.

Comment: In this way, it'll be possible to use UITextFieldDelegate to measure pressure speed on keys but not pressure force. My demand may sound a little bit strange for a commercial app but it's not the case. I'll use keystroke data for research purposes.

Comment: Yes, it does not give you pressure data. If research is your purpose, give a thought on why is it necessary to base your research on Apple provided keyboard and not any other sort of keyboard view (that would still be based on public APIs like UIView)

Comment: Because if this research will give satisfying results, I may develop an SDK in which user keystroke (and many other useful data) can be tracked to enhance security of the target app. In the target app, most likely the system keyboard will be used. Btw I achieved to access layers behind the keyboard in a way but adding gesture recognizer to them isn't working.

Comment: Edited with UIWindow extension.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I appreciate it. However, when I add the above extension, the keyboard become nonfunctional. The taps on keys don't enter the corresponding character to the text field. Do you have an idea to fix it?

Comment: @Nirav_Bhatt Could you find a solution?

Comment: Hi Dorukahn & Nirav,
I am also looking for same like key press and release time in system keyboard. I tried your way but I dint get any results.